# How to implement an exceptions in fullcalendar's business hours?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, scheduler, fullcalendar-scheduler

Casual situation in my project: fullcalendar+scheduler, only agenda view, every day different business hours. For example in monday:

```
{
  start: '08:00',
  end: '16:00',
  dow: [1]
}
```

I would like to set specyfic hours only in 17.09.2018. Is there any simple way to make it? I've already tried events rendering in background, but it's gone in case when we want to make busniess hours longer. How can I set start = 05:00 and end = 20:00 only in day above?